# Using the return value of strstr() in NASM?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to use the strstr C function in a NASM assembly program but cannot seem to get it to print out correctly.  I have tried multiple variations of this, but I think I may be misinterpreting how NASM returns the pointer value from C as I either get a blank line returned in the printf or a '(null)'.  Could some help fill me in as why I cannot get the correct return value to be printed?

```
section .data

    str1 db "Here is some text with a word",0x0A,0x00
    str2 db "text",0x0A, 0x00
    strFmt db "%s",0x0A,0x00

    global _start
    extern printf
    extern strstr

section .text

_start:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esi

    push str2
    push str1
    call strstr
    add esp, 8

    mov dword [myString], eax

    push dword [myString]
    push strFmt
    call printf
    add esp, 8

_exit:
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: This looks like a typo: `mov ebp, esi`. I'll bet you meant for the source to be `esp` there. Also, what is `myString`? That's not defined in the code you've shown, even though you use it. Why not just `push eax` directly?

Comment: I see you use `int 0x80`, so I assume this is Linux or macOS. Please, next time, add this information in your question. Things are slightly different on, say, Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is the `0x0A` in the search string. It's a part of the string, as everything before the terminating null is a part of it. It must be listed separately because [C-style escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences) inside strings won't be resolved by the assembler. A "test\n" won't be found by `strstr`. Remove the `0x0A` and `strstr` will found the search string.

As Cody Gray mentioned, the block with `mov ebp, esi` is strange—you probably meant the idiomatic `mov ebp, esp`. Moreover, it's not needed in this example. Also superfluous is the indirection with `myString`—just `push eax` directly.

`printf` writes the output first to a buffer. You exit the program with a `int 80h` system call. This call will destroy everything of the process including the printf-buffer. So the buffer won't be outputted. There are two ways to solve the problem:

1) Use the C function `exit` instead of the system call:

```
section .data
    str1 db "Here is some text with a word",0x0A,0x00
    str2 db "text",0x00
    strFmt db "%s",0x0A,0x00

global _start
extern printf, strstr, exit

section .text

_start:

    push str2
    push str1
    call strstr
    add esp, 8

    push eax
    push strFmt
    call printf
    add esp, 8

_exit:
    push 0
    call exit
```

2) Add a call to the C function `fflush`:

```
section .data
    str1 db "Here is some text with a word",0x0A,0x00
    str2 db "text",0x00
    strFmt db "%s",0x0A,0x00

global _start
extern printf, strstr, fflush

section .text

_start:

    push str2
    push str1
    call strstr
    add esp, 8

    push eax
    push strFmt
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    push 0
    call fflush

_exit:
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Yes I did mean to have esp and not esi there.  Also, I missed copying the section .data where I defined myString.  Is there a way to remove a null terminator like 0x0A from an input command line argument read in?  So instead of using str2, have strstr search for a command line argument string in str1.  I tried doing that but when you read in a command line arg you get the terminating char at the end of the string.

Comment: @SamIvanecky: 0x0A is not the null terminator, but a linefeed (= new line). The null terminator is 0x00, not part of the string, signalizes the C function  the end of the string and should not be removed. There could be many reasons why your access to the command line fails. You should ask a new question with a corresponding [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).